# Mongoose schemas type and ref? are they key words for .populate method? or are they arbitrary words?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database-schema

I am trying to create a data association in Mongoose using references, I want to add IDs from a commentSchema to my objectScehma. **I copied this code from somewhere and it works.**

My question is that-- the **names of key** used for objects in the comment array: **type** and **ref**-- are these two words sometype of keys words in mongoose, that are used by the .populate method??? or can we name these two keys anything? I have copy pasted my code below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!!

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var objectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        image: String,
        description: String,
        comments:[
                {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: "comment"
                }
        ]
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model("campground", objectSchema)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **type** and **ref**-- are these two words sometype of keys words in mongoose, (...)

Yes they are. Internally, mongoose uses these two keys in its algorithm to setup your mongoose models. You can see the usage of `type` key here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema.js#L358

And you are free to override it as documented here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey

As for `ref`, if I recall correctly, mongoose keeps a "cache" of all the model definitions internally and uses the `ref` key to quickly obtain the model definition of its internal list. I could be wrong on that so don't take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: If this answer satisfies your question, please mark it as correct.